# Create PDF file using TCPDF and display Existing pdf files inside that new file in php

Tags: php, tcpdf

I'm creating PDF file by using TCPDF and need to display existing PDF files in that TCPDF PDF file.

For example: I need to create PDF file for user and display their activities and attached files into that PDF, If there are images then it's displaying but pdf is not displayed inside that PDF file.

Is it possible to display existing PDF files in the new TCPDF PDF file?.

Or is there any way to achieve it?.

Thank in advance.

Comment: Your question seems to be the question that can be answered by googling or reading documentations... Stackoverflow is more for helping you with issues rather than such broad questions.